# Gas bottle stuck to the floor, why did it happen?

Tags: thermodynamics

So I decided to do some bbq for new year's eve.  It's snowing here and the floor may be below 0. What I would have never expected is that the gas bottle would get stuck to the floor so strong that I cannot detach it now.

Why do you think it happen? Does the gas bottle get colder when in use for some thermodynamic law? I don't really see how. Ok that gas is leaving the bottle through a small valve,  but eventhough...

Besides, I tried to pour some boiling water around the base but it's like welded to the floor. Do you think it'd safe to pour more water?

[image]

Comment: Indoor? Outdoor? Wet? Dry? Wood floor? Dirt? Concrete? Marble? Carpet?

Comment: Outdoor, wet floor. Concrete.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using the fuel, the liquid propane goes through a phase change into a gaseous state. The remaining liquid becomes colder because vaporization takes heat energy. You can see the frost line on the outside of the canister, this is the approximate level of the cooled liquid inside the tank. If temperatures are already close to 0°C the cooling liquid could easily drop it below 0°C freezing any condensation or water between the tank and the floor. If gas is not being used for a while the tank will slowly warm up to the surrounding temperature. It should be safe to pour some warm water on the  base as it would take a good bit to heat the propane to a dangerous temperature which would be a lot higher than 0°C.

Comment: If paranoid, use 30°C warm water. A propane bottle can *trivially* handle a warm day without bursting.

Comment: I would think it unlikely that evaporative cooling was the main cause, because the metal base would have kept the gas container part from touching the floor.  More likely is that the container was warm from being kept inside, so it melted existing ice on the floor, which then refroze.

Comment: @jamesqf Perhaps, but from the frost level on the canister I doubt the liquid propane was at or warmer than the outside temperature.